# How to change the jQuery effect duration time in button event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have set effects on my UI dialog on show and hide:

```
show: {
  effect: "blind",
  duration: 600
},
hide: {
  effect: "explode",
  duration: 1000
},
```

I also have a few buttons, and I would like to set different effects on pressing them with closing dialog. The problem is that effects are showing too fast.

Here's my code for the buttons:

```
buttons: {
  Yes: function () {
    $(this).dialog("option", "hide", "explode").dialog("close");
  },
```

How do you set the effect duration time in the method `.dialog("option",...,...)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an object defining the effect and duration as the third parameter:

```
buttons: {
    Yes: function () {
        $(this).dialog("option", "hide", {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 100
        }).dialog("close");
    },
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKW36/) for a demo